# nHibernate abstractCriterion and making dynamically query

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, dynamic

What i need to do is make query in nHibernate (fully dynamically i don't know how many objects i will have).

What this query should returns are objects of specific Ids(i got `List<int>`).

Is there any way to make restriction like

```
Restrictions.Eq("Id",first item from my list of ints).Or("Id",second item) .... and so on.
```

I know i can make it with `AbstractCriterion` but have no idea how to check if object from my `List<int>` is first one.

So how can I make that?

Thanks for advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `In` criteria:

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(XYZ))
.Add(Expression.In("Id", values))
```

Comment: values are List of some objects in my case list of ints?

Comment: Thi. Although keep in mind that NHibernate will send each value as a parameter. So if you have a large array, you will run up against the parameter size limit.

Comment: what size limit are in nHibernate @Vadim?

Comment: It's not dependent on the size limit in NHibernate, but on the database you're using.

Comment: Yes. `values` in this case will be list of ints. In case of SQL Server the limit of parameters passed is 2100.